# Transition effects not working on tablet

Tags: android, uiviewanimationtransition

I had used a transition animation in my application.it runs well on emulator and displaying effects on it.
But when i run the application on tablet it displays nothing only normal splash screen effect.
is there any change in code or declare something in manifest.
please help.

Thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
package com.comply.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

   public class Activity02 extends Activity {   

   private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 5000;    

   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.page02);         
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override          
        public void run() {                        
            /* Create an intent that will start the main activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Activity02.this, Activity03.class);
            Activity02.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

            /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
            Activity02.this.finish();

            /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
            }   
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);            
    }
}
```

Comment: could you help me too..